# Select2 4.0.0 - change inputbox height

Tags: javascript, css

whenever I use select2, the empty box is just one line high.
When input is added, the box expands accordingly, but always just the exact amount needed.

How can I change it so my input box is at least 100px high, even if empty? In some cases, I expect the box to be 100px or even higher when filled, so it looks really dumb in my layout, if the box is just 16px high in the first place.

[image: image of my select2 element]

The HTML element to which I'm applying select2() is a Select element with "multiple=multiple" (I need multiple inputs eventually.)

I googled a lot, and also searched in this forum, but nothing worked so far.
I tried including something like this in my custom css file:

```
.select2-container .select2-choice {
min-height:100px !important;
}
```

But it didnt't change anything. Maybe those tipps are for older versions of select2? I'm using 4.0.0.

How can I enlarge the box?

**Solution:**

I added this to my css. It's all about getting the css selectors right (which indeed seem to have changed, recently). I extracted their names by inspecting my HTML output.

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{
    min-height:100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

[image: where i Found the css selectors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.select2-selection.select2-selection--multiple {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Tested on the [examples page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would just pad the select2-choices container a bit so you can still have a dynamic height but be sure that the element can never make contact with the bottom of the container. You can also put the min-height here I think.

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  min-height: 26px;
}
```

Comment: none of the styles I'm trying to add show any effect

Comment: ok I tried to work with what I found in "inspect element":

this works right now: .select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{
 min-height:100px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}