# Select2 4.0.0: different box heights for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, css

I just found out how to set the height of a select2 inputbox. [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610524/select2-4-0-0-change-inputbox-height)

Now I have another problem.

Some boxes should be just one line high (default), others 100px, and others 200px, for example.

Right now, I'm using this css for a big input box

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{
    min-height:100px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

But this obviously changes the height of all boxes on the page.

How can I adjust the height for individual boxes?

Comment: You can either create two separate classes for them - each with the desired heights or do that dynamically. What's your problem here, can you be more specific?

Comment: I don't know how to name the classes and how to invoke them. .select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{} is normally included in the Select2 css, so I just needed to overwrite it. Here I don't know how/where to include a "foreign" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you have to assign the css class in the constructor of the select2 element (in the JS part).

In containerclass, you can simply pass multiple different classes that should be applied, seperated by space. `tpx-select2-container` is a skin I'm using, while `select2-bigbox` and `select2-small` are the classes I wrote myself.

Their content simply looks like this:
`.select2-bigbox{
    min-height:300px !important;
}`

```
 $("#bigbox").select2({
        //select2 parameters
        containerCssClass: 'tpx-select2-container select2-bigbox',
    });


$("#smallbox").select2({
    //select2 parameters
    containerCssClass: 'tpx-select2-container select2-smallbox',
 });
```

The problem with on my side was that I mixed up "classA classB classC" in CSS invokation with "classA classB classC" in CSS definition.

In **definition** of CSS `.classA .classB{ }` means: "for every classB element found inside classA, apply the following".

In **invokation** of CSS `<element class="classA classB">` means: "apply all styles of both classA and classB".

Answer (score 1):

Add the following class in the `Select2.css` after the existing class

```
.select2-container-bigger{
    min-height:200px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And create your elements as below:-

```
<span class="select2-container">
  <input type="text" 
       id="text1" class="select2-selection--multiple"/>
  <input type="text" 
       id="text2" class="select2-container-bigger"/>
</span>
```

Notice how the `css class` is defined in the file. It is `select2-container` followed by `select2-selection--multiple`. Hence, the latter should be enclosed within an element having the former class.

In our case, the input element bearing `id="text1"` is enclosed within a span element of class type `select2-container`. Hence, assigning the *"child"* class to the inner element. So, structure your elements in correlation to the `CSS` class structure and assign the desired classes to the corresponding elements.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, because I tried manually assigning classes to the actual html input elements before, which didn't do anything.

I think it must be done inside javascript, because the select2 element is created at runtime. (see my answer).

Still giving a thumbs up for your effort.

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that the elements were created by JS at runtime.